# Flow - maybe type incompatible with union types

Tags: javascript, flowtype

Flow code can be [run here.](https://flow.org/try/#0C4TwDgpgBAaghgGwK4QCrmgXilAzsAJwEsA7AcygB8oSkBbAIwgKqgYHt2FXaFvqAbuyIATANwAoUJCgB5BgCsIAY2CyAZvGQRcUbAG8A2vmLkAugC5YiFOkgBfCeqQlVRdiShkIwLSgBiBOx08kqqGn46ABTsiipqmjY6VqHxEUm4ADQ0cHQQViakZACUVpF20PoSOAQ+SASesWEJkbiGJLkQZpKOElIYUADKwRCRAOpEwAAWAHJIfHAMCBCDhEV6UFU4uCMACkGQBKBWAPyF5BK9Ti5uHl4+kVBRO3mpqlbDeeOTs-MIi8tVqYSptqlBasB6p5vL4koFgm8WhlniNEdkAOQvCD7diHUDo4o9IA)

Using flow, I have a function that takes a key value pair object and gets a value for it - the value it gets should be a string, number or boolean.

```
type ValueType =  string | number | bool | null | void;
type ObjectOfValues = {[string]: ValueType}
function getValueFromObjectOfValues(objectOfValues: ObjectOfValues, name: string): ValueType {
  return objectOfValues[name];
}
```

I define some object type that has a property that's a `maybe` string:

```
type SomeValueWithNullableString = {
  someProperty: ?string
}
```

Then I create a function that takes my specific object type and calls the function to get a value from it:

```
function getValue (someObject: SomeValueWithNullableString) {
  return getValueFromObjectOfValues(someObject, 'someProperty');
}
```

This results in a flow error:

> type ObjectOfValues = {[string]: ValueType}
>                                       ^ boolean. This type is incompatible with the expected param type of someProperty:
>   ?string                    ^ string 2: type ObjectOfValues =
>   {[string]: ValueType}
>                                       ^ number. This type is incompatible with the expected param type of 9:   someProperty:
>   ?string                    ^ string

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2):

The problem with this code is that the objects are mutable, so `getValueFromObjectOfValues` could legally do `objectOfValues.someProperty = 5`.

If Flow allowed this subtyping relationship, then the original caller, who thought they had an object where `someProperty` had type `?string`, would now have an object where `someProperty` had type `number`, thereby breaking the type system.

To solve this problem, you can use [property variance](https://flow.org/blog/2016/10/04/Property-Variance/). You need to change your type like this:

`type ObjectOfValues = {+[string]: ValueType}`

This means, loosely, that if you have an object of type `ObjectOfValues`, all you know is that its properties are some subtype of `ValueType`. This means that when you read from them, you will get a `ValueType`. But Flow won't let you write to them, since it doesn't know what type they actually are -- just that they are a subtype of `ValueType`.